# Is there a way to handle app close/kill/termination in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I have a react native app, I want to do some cleanup functions when the app is closed/killed/terminated by the user.

I tried putting my functions in a `useEffect` in my App component, and calling them in the `return` block, but that isn't working on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

There are some libraries to handle this. but you can just introduce an error your self.

```
const killMe = (empty) => empty.crash
```

This way everytime you call killme and don't pass a value react native will try to access "crash" as it doesn't exist it will crash the app or "close it"